# Django ForeignKey Relationship Constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Can I enforce a `ForeignKey` relationship such that an **Article** written by a **Reporter** cannot be written by another **Reporter**?

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

I'm trying to implement "object containment" and support assignment of **Articles** to **Reporter** "folders".

For example, a *ReporterOne* "folder" contains *Articles A,B,C* and if *Articles A,B,C* are "assigned to" (i.e. contained within) *ReporterOne's* folder, they **cannot be assigned** to *ReporterTwo*.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/). From the docs:

> To define a one-to-one relationship, use OneToOneField. In this example a **Place** optionally can be a **Restaurant**:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the place" % self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place, primary_key=True)
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the restaurant" % self.place.name

class Waiter(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the waiter at %s" % (self.name, self.restaurant)
```

Comment: How does that enforce containment of Article A in only ReporterOne's folder? Seems like that only ensures one article per one reporter, but not specific articles in only one folder.

Answer (score 0):

`Article` has `ForeignKey` to `Reporter`. As such each `Article` will only belong to one `Reporter`. Then add an attribute called `folder` to `Article`  and use it as a hash key to determine what `Articles` are "contained" in a `folder`.

To find all the `Articles` that are in a `folder` called `Foo` for a given `Reporter` you could do a query like this:

```
reporter = Reporter.objects.first()
articles_in_folder = reporter.articles_set.filter(folder='Foo')
```

Note that `folder` could also be an entire model and not just a string. An `Article` would have a ForeingKey to `folder` and `folder` could also have a `ForeingKey` to `Reporter`.

Comment: You could also do Reporter - ForeingKey -> Folder - ForeingKey -> Article, but that would require the existence of a Folder to have Articles.